# Como alternar los colores de mi tabla

Tags: php, mysql

Quiero alternar los colores de mi tabla que obtiene los resultados de la base de datos, estos los recibe de otra pagina que los va subiendo como ordenes y quisiera que se altere el color saltando un regristro.
Como se los comente, esta tabla se crea con los registros que se van insertando desde otra pagina y necesito por ejemplo que la primera sea blanca, la segunda gris y asi con cada uno de los registros que llegen.
Quiero alternar los colores de mi tabla que obtiene los resultados de la base de datos, estos los recibe de otra pagina que los va subiendo como ordenes y quisiera que se altere el color saltando un regristro.
Como se los comente, esta tabla se crea con los registros que se van insertando desde otra pagina y necesito por ejemplo que la primera sea blanca, la segunda gris y asi con cada uno de los registros que llegen.

```html
<!-- inicio limitador vista PURCHASE  -->
 <?php if ($tipo_usuario == 1 or $tipo_usuario == 2) { ?>


<!-- Page Heading -->
<div class="d-sm-flex align-items-center justify-content-between mb-4">
    <h1 class="h3 mb-0 text-gray-800">Open Orders Menu</h1>
</div>

<!-- Content Row -->
<div class="row">
<div class="card-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">
        <form action="buscar_usuario.php" method="get" class="form_search">
            <input type="text" name="busqueda" id="busqueda" placeholder="Search">
            <input type="submit" value="Buscar" class="btn_search">
        </form>
            <table class="table table-bordered" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>ID</th>                   
                        <th>Customer Name</th>
                        <th>PO #</th>
                        <th>MATERIAL</th>
                        <th>Color</th>
                        <th>Finish</th>
                        <th>Digital Proof</th>
                        <th>--</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tfoot>
                   
                </tfoot>
                <tbody>
                <?php 
//paginar
$sql_register = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT COUNT(*) as total_registro FROM quotes");
$result_register = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_register);
$total_registro = $result_register['total_registro'];

$por_page = 10; // limitador de registros

if(empty($_GET['pagina'])){
    $pagina =1;
}else{
    $pagina= $_GET['pagina'];
}

$desde = ($pagina-1) * $por_page;
$total_paginas = ceil($total_registro / $por_page);
//paginar

            $sql = "SELECT * from quotes  WHERE status=1 ORDER BY quote_id ASC LIMIT $desde,$por_page";
            $result = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

            while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            ?>
           
           <form method="post" action="purchase_See.php">
                     <tr >
                        <th><?php echo $mostrar['join_date'] ?></th>
                        <th><?php echo $mostrar['quote_id'] ?></th>
                        <th><?php echo $mostrar['username'] ?></th>
                        <th><?php echo $mostrar['pio_num'] ?></th>
                        <th><?php echo $mostrar['material_cat_name'] ?></th>
                        <th><?php echo $mostrar['colors_cat_name'] ?></th>
                        <th><?php echo $mostrar['finish_cat_name'] ?></th>
                        <th><?php echo $mostrar['proof_cat_name'] ?></th>
                        <th> <a  class="btn btn-success" href="purchase_See.php?id_P=<?php echo $mostrar['quote_id'];?>" ?>See order</a></th> 
                      <!--  <th> <button  class="btn btn-success" id="<?php echo $mostrar['quote_id'] ?> " >See order</button> -->
                        <input type="hidden" name="id_P" id="id_P" value="<?php echo $mostrar['quote_id']; ?>"></th>
                        
                    </tr>
                    </form>
                    <?php  } ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
            <div class="paginador">
                        <ul>
                            <?php
                            if ($pagina != 1) {
                            ?>
                            <li><a href="?pagina=<?php echo 1; ?>">|<<</a></li>
                            <li><a href="?pagina=<?php echo $pagina-1; ?>"><<<</a></li>
                            <?php } ?>
                          <?php 
                          for($i=1; $i <= $total_paginas; $i++){
                              if ($i == $pagina) {
                                echo '<li class="pageSelected">'.$i.'</li>';
                              }else{
                                echo '<li><a href="?pagina='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
                              }
                          }
                          if ($pagina != $total_paginas) {
                          ?>
                            <li><a href="?pagina=<?php echo $pagina+1; ?>">>>></a></li>
                            <li><a href="?pagina=<?php echo $total_paginas; ?>">>>|</a></li>
                            <?php } ?>
                        </ul>


                    </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
 <?php } ?>
 <!-- fin limitador vista PURCHASE  -->
```

Answer (score 0):

No se si es a lo que te refieres, pero para dale colores a tu tabla deberías usar CSS

```
tr:nth-child(odd){
 background-color: color;
}
```

Comment: Si exacto, ya hice eso, pero no funciona, solo funciona con la parte del <thead>, que tengo escrito, cuando aplico para el <tbody> que es donde mustran los campos de la base de datos no funciona

Answer (score 0):

### Cambiar el color de fondo fila de por medio

En `Bootstrap` existe la clase [`table-striped`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/content/tables/#striped-rows) la cual da el efecto visual que estas necesitando.

**Ejemplo**:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col">#</th>
      <th scope="col">First</th>
      <th scope="col">Last</th>
      <th scope="col">Handle</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">1</th>
      <td>Mark</td>
      <td>Otto</td>
      <td>@mdo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">2</th>
      <td>Jacob</td>
      <td>Thornton</td>
      <td>@fat</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">3</th>
      <td>Larry</td>
      <td>the Bird</td>
      <td>@twitter</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

### Errores de markup

Una etiqueta [`<tr>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tr) puede ser hija de un `<table>`, `<thead>`, `<tbody>` o `<tfooter>`. Con esto quiero señalar que el `<form>` no debería estar donde lo has puesto (*padre/contenedor de los `<tr>`*).

En el navegador se ve bien pero eso se debe a que éste, al analizar el `HTML`, realiza cambios automáticos para corregir errores como estos.

El `HTML` correcto para la `<table>` **podría** ser la siguiente:

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped" id="dataTable" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>ID</th>
      <th>Customer Name</th>
      <th>PO #</th>
      <th>MATERIAL</th>
      <th>Color</th>
      <th>Finish</th>
      <th>Digital Proof</th>
      <th>--</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>

  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <?php 
//paginar
$sql_register = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT COUNT(*) as total_registro FROM quotes");
$result_register = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_register);
$total_registro = $result_register['total_registro'];

$por_page = 10; // limitador de registros

if (empty($_GET['pagina'])) {
    $pagina =1;
} else {
    $pagina= $_GET['pagina'];
}

$desde = ($pagina-1) * $por_page;
$total_paginas = ceil($total_registro / $por_page);
//paginar

$sql = "SELECT * from quotes  WHERE status=1 ORDER BY quote_id ASC LIMIT $desde,$por_page";
$result = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);

while ($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) { ?>

    <tr>
      <th>
        <?php echo $mostrar['join_date'] ?>
      </th>
      <th>
        <?php echo $mostrar['quote_id'] ?>
      </th>
      <th>
        <?php echo $mostrar['username'] ?>
      </th>
      <th>
        <?php echo $mostrar['pio_num'] ?>
      </th>
      <th>
        <?php echo $mostrar['material_cat_name'] ?>
      </th>
      <th>
        <?php echo $mostrar['colors_cat_name'] ?>
      </th>
      <th>
        <?php echo $mostrar['finish_cat_name'] ?>
      </th>
      <th>
        <?php echo $mostrar['proof_cat_name'] ?>
      </th>
      <th>
        <a class="btn btn-success" href="purchase_See.php?id_P=<?php echo $mostrar['quote_id'];?>" ?>See order</a>
      </th>
    </tr>
    <?php  } ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**PD**: Digo podría, porque al parecer el `<form>` no hace falta, ni el `<input hidden>` y también habia un `</th>` de más.